# CategoryID/ParentCategoryID Looping Help

Tags: sql, categories

How do you get away with generating a tabbed list of CategoryID/ParentCategoryID the simplest way?  I am no SQL expert, but logically, this is very difficult for me..

Can it be done with 1 or 2 SQL statements, maybe a Do/Loop For/Next would work?

The list should look like this:

Category
-Subcategory
--SubSubcategory
---InfiniteSubcategories

Category
-etc..
--etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read up on thing called "Closure Tables". It might make few things easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly not an easy problem(if performance is of any importance), so it might be a good idea to read up on [some](http://kylecordes.com/2008/transitive-closure) of the [solutions](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/nestedsets.aspx) that are [scattered](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) on the [internet](http://sqlteam.com/article/more-trees-hierarchies-in-sql).

For a simple(and not at all well suited for tasks where performance is important) you can do this:

```
function readChildrenNodes(parentNode) {
    newNodes = sql_db.get("SELECT * FROM nodes WHERE parent="+parentNode.id);
    parentNode.appendChildren(newNodes);
    for node in newNodes
        readChildrenNodes(node);
}
```

Comment: parentNode = ParentCategoryID, Node=CategoryID. It is easier to talk about Nodes because what you are describing is a tree structure, it's a mathematical convention.

Comment: Do you know it in VBScript, classic ASP?

Comment: I never used those languages, but you can write my psudo-code in any language you want.